# How to display data coming from the controller as collection in a ViewData dynamically Highcharts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts, bar-chart

The data in the controller is collected from the SQL database correctly, also it does exist in the viewData in view Cshtml.

///Model

```
    public class ChartViewModel
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfCases { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public ChartViewModel(int year, int weeknr, int number, int size)
    {
        Year = year;
        WeekNumber = weeknr;
        NumberOfCases = number;
        Size = size;
    }
}

public class ChartViewModelsList
{
    public List<ChartViewModel> List { get; set; }

    public ChartViewModelsList()
    {
        List = new List<ChartViewModel>();
    }
}
```

///Controller

```
        public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";


        //fill the data for the chart
        //create a new, empty list
        Models.CaseMetricsList model = new Models.CaseMetricsList();

        //load the csv file into the model (list)
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select top(25) DATEPART(year, InsertedDateTime) as yearnr, DATEPART(week, InsertedDateTime) as weeknr,  count(*) as numberofcases,  sum(sourcecasesize) as Size from tblcases where CaseStatusId <> 4 group by DATEPART(year, InsertedDateTime), DATEPART(week, InsertedDateTime) order by DATEPART(year, InsertedDateTime), DATEPART(week, InsertedDateTime) asc ", sqlConn))
        {
            // create the DataSet 
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            // fill the DataSet using our DataAdapter 
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[0];
           
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                model.List.Add(new Models.CaseMetricsModel(Convert.ToInt32(dr["Yearnr"]),
                                                     Convert.ToInt32(dr["weeknr"].ToString()),
                                                     Convert.ToInt32(dr["numberofcases"]),
                                                     Convert.ToInt32(dr["Size"])));
            }


            ViewData["usaData"] = model;

        }

        return View();

    }
```

///View

```
   <script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'New cases in Relativity per week'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: [
            @foreach(var item in @ViewData["usaData"] as IEnumerable<ChartViewModel>)
            {
                @item.List.Select(x => x.WeekNumber)
            }
        ],
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: '# cases'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Number of new cases per week.'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year/week',
        color: '#009286',
        data: @foreach(var item in @ViewData["usaData"] as IEnumerable<ChartViewModel>)
               {
                @item.List.Select(x => x.NumberOfCases)
               }
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
</script>
```

But the chart is not being displayed and the @foreach is returning an exception.
How should the data in the view(using viewData or ViewBag) be displayed in order to display the graph correctly?.
Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest avoid using ViewDta/Bag and have a model that wraps your model so that you have a properly typed ViewModel that is what they are for. It will also help avoid casting/boxing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should assign

```
ViewData["usaData"] = model.List;
```

And in view

```
@foreach(var item in @ViewData["usaData"] as IEnumerable<CaseMetricsModel>)
```

Comment: Hi Midhun, thank you firstly for your reaction and I hope you are doing well. so yes by using your suggestion I'm able to get the data in the cshtml file but the problem that the chart still is not working